# How to backup data on my home drive from a Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 that crashed?

Tags: 12.04, 10.10

I booted the system from ubuntu 12.0.4 desktop lts  live usb ... Now i need to know how I could access/backup the data on my home drive?

When i boot i only see the file system for the bootable usb drive and folders such as desktop etc... I do not see any option to access the file system for the crashed os on the hard drive of my laptop...

Comment: Is your home drive encrypted?

Comment: well i didn't encrypt anything...additional info submitted in original question...

Answer (score -1):

Siply go under root in terminal type su (on live media it has no password)< mount your home partition and than you can perform any data manipulations with your user home directory

Comment: In Ubuntu `su` will not work to become root, even on a live CD. [`sudo` is used instead.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) But `sudo` is not required to mount the partition; the OP can just select it from the devices menu in Nautilus! (Nautilus is the file manager.)

Comment: what command do you type to mount the hard drive on the laptop?

Comment: @EliahKagan how do we access nautilus?

Comment: @user481913 Click (or double-click) a folder icon. If you open any folder, you can mount whatever (attached) devices you like. Or you can press Alt+F2 and run the command `nautilus`. If you find you're unable to copy the files, you can run `gksu nautilus`. That runs Nautilus [as root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). Please be very careful with this. (I'm pretty sure this has already been asked and answered...I'm looking...)

Comment: +1 Thanks Eliah ... I can access the old home dir now... I wasn't sure how to do this through Nautilus as it wouldn't show me an option to access the same ... However i noticed a option for Dash Home - Documents on the bottom panel and it did show me an option for accessing  the crashed 500 gb hard drive...